# Where can I find information about "stone power" / lapidaire?

Tags: middle-ages, cultural-history, history-of-ideas

While doing some research about Middle-Ages jewelry, where stones comes from and the economy around it, I found a website mentioning this [book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/pierres-du-moyen-age-anthologie-des-lapidaires-medievaux/oclc/961183481) and mention beliefs in some magical properties of precious or semi-precious stone.

I am looking for historical sources about the belief in the 'power' of stones in the Middle-Ages.

By "power of stones", I mean the magical properties people in the Middle-Ages thought that special or 'precious' stones had, but mainly separated from the 'medical' aspects often associated with this.

'Power' like "Grant wealthiness", or "make you invincible".

I only found websites about actual "lithotherapie", and a book on Amazon.

Specifically, I'm looking for information about what in French would be called a "lapidaire", from the Middle Ages, and ideally translated, but found nothing on the internet. Apparently some special terms or concepts for this elude me.

The works I found so far:

- Valérie Gontero-Lauze: "Les Pierres du Moyen Âge: Anthologie des lapidaires médiévaux" Relié – 10 octobre 2016. ([amazon link](https://www.amazon.fr/Pierres-Moyen-%C3%82ge-Anthologie-lapidaires/dp/2251445943))
- Pierre Genève: "Magie et Pouvoirs des Pierres", Science & Magie N° 59 ([PDF](http://www.science-et-magie.com/archives02num/sm59/5901pierres.pdf)) (this is more about new-age spirituality and esoterism. Not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: There's a kernel of an interesting question here; namely where do the beliefs in the powers of stone come from. Assuming that is what you intended to ask, and FWIW, when I looked it up out of curiosity a few years ago I failed to locate any online sources that were worth reading. It was mostly hocus pocus websites operated by a laundry list of unscrupulous stone vendors, Goop types of websites, and astrology or tarot or new age healthy living types of websites -- none of them no sources. You might be luckier looking into Scholarly work and books written by historians, assuming any.

Comment: I was looking for something like this, and I found this (but a lot of pages are not readable): https://books.google.fr/books?id=yJMvREyUW0oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lapidaire+moyen+age&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5g7bkp8jkAhWDxoUKHQlyC_EQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=lapidaire%20moyen%20age&f=false

Comment: Please clarify everything enhancing the question in the question with an [edit]. I started an answer below. Please refine your question further or comment to indicate your exact direction of inquiry.

Comment: @dorianturba *don't comment*. Edit the question so that all the information is in the question

Comment: For me, all information is in the question. Previous comment is a responce to the comment by Denis de Bernardy only. It does not improve the question.

Comment: @DorianTurba Telling people where you have already searched, what you found, and why that didn't suffice helps us to avoid duplicating your research or giving answers that don't meet your needs.  That is why all information needs to be included in the question.  As the help text says: "_Avoid answering questions in comments_".  Furthermore, as a general rule  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030).

Comment: LangLangC answer my question. I found the question correct and the answer perfectly fit it. I have accepted the answer, because it is what I want. In comment, I made a little clarification, not enough important for me to edit the question. I think it belong to the comments.

Comment: "I found the question correct and the answer perfectly fit it. I have accepted the answer, because it is what I want." And yet your comment beneath that answer - and your edit to the question just now - suggests that you're looking for something *completely different* to what that answer discusses.

Comment: It's just a precision about a question in the answer. For me, the "important" part of the answer is this : "To find more info one needs to search for "lapidary" in English and include terms like "magic"." And it's exactly what I ask : Where to look ?

Comment: Ok, granted that the question is probably not overly perfectly phrased and might benefit from improvements still. But could those close-voters who ticked "not about history" please comment here to explain how that is 'the correct close reason', or better yet: comment on how one should improve this question? (I suspect a misreading: taking this Q as 'request for esoteric guidance in the modernist world'?)

Comment: @LangLangC I'm not one of those who voted to close, but it reads to me rather like "_what are the correct search terms I should be using in Google_" (especially in the light of the OP's comment above).  If that really is what is being asked, is that a question about History?  (Personally, I agree that "_Unclear what you're asking_" might have made more sense as a reason, but I am loath to overturn a community vote)

Comment: @sempaiscuba I am not requesting an 'overturn'. I'd like to help edit this into better shape, and for that, I see 4 CVs that lead to a banner that doesn't help much here (If it *were true:* Q probably unsalvagable) But as said, guess is 4 voters misread it. I am quite shy to wield either scalpel or chisel for editing this, given the info I gleaned from community comments. But 'unclear' is usually the category that in principle *we can* edit into shape?

Comment: How can I improve the question to be clearer ?

Comment: I propose a new title in order to make it clearer, is this better ?

Comment: I try to avoid closing a question with an accepted, upvoted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed difficult to find with a simple web-search reliable information about a scientifically mostly discredited idea, that nevertheless still enjoys enormous popularity in esoteric circles. Such a configuration seems to dominate the search algorithms. The French search term [*lapidaires*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapidaires) is equally contaminated with very modern explanations about crafts in jewelry. To find more info one needs to search for "[lapidary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapidary_(text))" in English and include terms like "magic".

> In the thirteenth century an amazing development occurred in philosophy. Leading philosophers began to look at magic and its practices with different eyes than the ancient Church Fathers and distanced themselves from the devastating judgments of the older theorist of Christianity.
>   Between the time of Augustine and the High Middle Ages there was a significant upheaval in the assessment of this phenomenon. The new philosophers of the Latin West knew exactly what the influential clerical critics had to say about magic. Because they no longer let themselves be guided by earlier prejudices in forming their opinions, however, the term 'magic' stepped out of its negative aura and suddenly took on a more positive meaning.
>   <sub>–– Udo Reinhold Jeck: ["Virtus Lapidum.- Zur Philosophischen Begründung Der Magischen Wirksamkeit Und Der Physikalischen Beschaffenheit Kostbarer Mineralien in Der Naturphilosophie Alberts Des Grossen"](https://doi.org/10.1163/157338200X00281), Early Science and Medicine, Volume 5: Issue 1, 2000.</sub>

If "power of stones" is meant to be restricted to medical applications, then ["lithothérapie"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithoth%C3%A9rapie) as a term seems to be an accepted French term, but in other languages seems to be reserved now for decidedly *modern* esoteric use. ["Crystal healing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_healing) in English and ["Heilsteine"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heilstein) (healing stones) in Germany would cover both historic and modern uses.

> The term “lapidary medicine” does not appear in current historical surveys on the topic of medieval or early modern healing. It is a term I coined to define an idea and practice that played an integral role in pre-modern health care in the West, a practice that has thus far been largely ignored by researchers.
>   <sub>–– Nichola Erin Harris: ["The Idea of Lapidary Medicine: Its Circulation and Practical Applications in Medieval and Early Modern England: 1000-1750"](https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/25823/), Dissertation, Rutgers, 2009.</sub>

Christopher J. Duffin: ["The western lapidary tradition in early geological literature: medicinal and magical minerals"](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2451.2005.00491.x), Geology Today, Volume 21, Issue 2, Pages 58-63, 2005.

Francis Young: ["A Medieval Book of Magical Stones: The Peterborough Lapidary"](https://books.google.com/books?id=eOU9DQAAQBAJ), LuLu, 2016.

Claude Lecouteux: ["A Lapidary of Sacred Stones: Their Magical and Medicinal Powers Based on the Earliset Sources"](https://books.google.com/books?id=0VooDwAAQBAJ), Simon and Schuster, 2012.

One thing to keep in mind is that most actually medieval sources will be more "integrative" than we like to see them. That means 'lapidary information' is mostly within other books, not even necessarily forming a separate chapter within them.

Further, what we now would probably 'clearly see' as separate attributes regarding these stones: giving 'invincibility' or 'power', or 'wealth', weren't distinct superstitions, but usually ones that came part and parcel with all other qualities in one package.

For example [Paracelsus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracelsus) likes to hide his 'lapidary information' in his *Philosophia:**

> Since you are auditores, listen and learn: from both sides and take from it what is useful. Unless you ruminate daily on the things I tell you—how else would you arrive at the foundation of medicine? [How else] will you get to know the microcosmus in external nature, in which you will comprehend wonders and great secret things that reside within the human being. Do not do this for my sake, but for your own and for the patients and in order that God should be praised. For who until now has understood the human being as a human being? All the faculties are blind to him and do not recognize him, whence nothing but ruination results. Indeed, even the theologians would have to be meekly quiet, if they were to become physicians in this sense. The jurists would know what their cleverness amounts to, how it comes only from them, and so on and so on. All of this because the human being is taken up, and no one now wants to recognize him as he truly is. For you would [know] metal in water, as well as metal in earth, as well as in fire, as well as in air. You would know [four] forms of *mercurius,* four of *betonica,* four of *tereniabin,* four *amethysts.* Between all there is no difference except form. There are four *chelidonia,* and four *orizon.* All these things are no different [in external reality] than they are in the human being. For he too is created fourfold and well formed [in this regard]. The knowledge, art, and secret powers of the physician reside in this formation; and he should proceed accordingly, and not follow after any other profession; for they are not suitable for him in his affairs. With this I hope to have demostrated to you the first ground of medicine, with sufficient conviction that [you can see that] without philosophy there can be no such thing as a physician, but rather only impostures that grow like moss on the trunk of a tree.
>   <sub>–– Andrew Weeks: "Paracelsus (Theophrastus Bombastus von Hohenheim, 1493–1541). Essential Theoretical Writings", Aries Book Series – Texts and Studies in Western Esotericism, Vol 5, Brill: Leiden, Boston, 2008.
>
>   <sup>* "The First Foundation of Medicine"</sup></sub>

An old German work would be 
Hermann Fühner: ["Lithotherapie. Historische Studien über die medizinische Verwendung der Edelsteine"](https://archive.org/details/lithotherapiehi00fhgoog/page/n6), Dissertation, S Calvary: Berlin, 1902.

George Frederick Kunz: ["The Curious Lore Of Precious Stones"](https://archive.org/details/curiousloreofpre028009mbp/page/n8), Halcyon House: New York, 1938.

The always productive [Hildegard von Bingen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_of_Bingen) wrote *Liber subtilitatum diversarum naturarum creaturarum* (Physica), and from that we could extract:

Peter Riethe: "Hildegard von Bingen. Das Buch von den Steinen. Nach den Quellen übersetzt und erläutert von Peter Riethe", Otto Müller Verlag: Salzburg, <sup>3</sup>1997.

The keywords under which these phenomena are analysed today include also "(western) esotericism", "magic", "amulets", "pendants" if the work is categorised in modern scholarship. Contemporary, especially later works *against*  such practices and believes might of course include "witchcraft" as well. From the works below it becomes clear that well known medieval authors and titles of their works would be the easiest way to go.

Roberta Gilchrist: ["Magic for the Dead? The Archaeology of Magic in Later Medieval Burials"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/174581708x335468), Medieval Archaeology 
Volume 52, 2008 - Issue 1, 2013.

B. Ann Tlusty: ["Invincible blades and invulnerable bodies: weapons magic in early-modern Germany"](https://doi.org/10.1080/13507486.2015.1028340), European Review of History: Revue européenne d'histoire, Volume 22, Issue 4: The History of Early Modern Masculinities; L'histoire des masculinités modernes, 2015.

John M. Riddle: ["Lithotherapy in the Middle Ages…: Lapidaries Considered as Medical Texts"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41109991), Pharmacy in History, 
Vol. 12, No. 2, pp. 39-50, 1970.

Not to overlook as an historical source are of course the remnants of these beliefs in fiction or poetic works:
Penelope B. R. Doob ["Chaucer's Corones Tweyne and the Lapidaries"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25093217), The Chaucer Review, Vol. 7, No. 2, pp. 85-96, 1972.

Marisa Galvez: "Dark Transparencies: Crystal Poetics in Medieval Texts and Beyond", Philological Quarterly, 2014. ([PDF](https://dlcl.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/files_upload/Galvez%20Pages%20from%20PQ%2093_1%20W14093%20-2.pdf))

Karen Overbey: ["Seeing through stone: Materiality and place in a medieval Scottish pendant reliquary"](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/691037), Res – Anthropology and aesthetics, Volume 65-66 | 2014/2015.

Ronnie H. Terpening: ["The lapidary of L'intelligenza: Its literary background"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01513585), Neophilologus, Volume 60, Issue 1, pp 75–88, 1976.

Gad Freudenthal and Jean-Marc Mandosio: ["Old French into Hebrew in Twelfth-Century Tsarfat: Medieval Hebrew Versions of Marbode's Lapidary"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2979/aleph.14.1.11), Aleph, Vol. 14, No. 1, pp. 11-187, 2014.

J. Horace Nunemaker: ["A Comparison of the Lapidary of Marbode with a Spanish Fifteenth-Century Adaptation"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2848829), Speculum, Vol. 13, No. 1, pp. 62-67, 1938.

Katelyn Mesler: ["The Medieval Lapidary of Techel/Azareus on Engraved Stones and Its Jewish Appropriations"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2979/aleph.14.2.75), Aleph
Vol. 14, pp. 75-143, 2014.

The most famous lapidary of the medieval period may be that of [Marbodius of Rennes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marbodius_of_Rennes).

John M. Riddle: "Marbode: De Lapidibus", 
Volumes 20-21 of Marbode of Rennes' De Lapidibus: Considered as a Medical Treatise with Text, Commentary, and C. W. King's Translation, Together with Text and Translation of Marbode's Minor Works on Stones, Marbode (Bishop of Rennes), Steiner, 1977.

De lapidis ou Liber lapidum, seu De gemmis, De lapidibus (avant 1090), in: Valérie Gontero-Lauze: "Sagesses minérales. Médecine et magie des pierres précieuses au Moyen Âge", Éditions Classiques Garnier: Paris, 2010, p151–176.

An older translation of Marbodius poems in the *Liber Lapidum* into French are online:

[Poèmes de Marbode : évêque de Rennes (XIe siècle) / traduits en vers français, avec une introduction par Sigismond Ropartz
Pagination avant numérisation : 227 pages. Reproduction numérique de l'édition imprimée à Rennes chez Verdier en 1873](http://bibnum.univ-rennes2.fr/items/show/693)

From that an excerpt from the translation concerning diamonds, disregarding the poetic verse:

> This stone is useful in the art of magic;
>   It fills the heart with strength and energy; It can dispel tiring dreams, night ghosts, larvae and ghosts; Destroy poison the fatal influence, soothe conflicts and heal dementia:
>   She knows how to avenge us on all our enemies. Put these precious gems on a bracelet, May the goldsmith set them in gold or silver; May this jewel always be placed in the sinister.

Quite an important medival German book, that not only lists but also explains the 'science' of stones to his readers would be *Daz Steinbuoch* by Volmar.

John Greenfield: ["A Sermon on Stones? A Note on Volmar's *Daz Steinbuoch*"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2846596), Linguas e Literaturas, 1995.
This introductory explanation seems necessary, for motivation, as the following old German text is not the easiest to read:

Volmar, Hans Lambel, St. Florianus, Heinrich: ["Das Steinbuch: Ein altdeutsches Gedicht"](https://archive.org/details/dassteinbuchein00heingoog/page/n8), G Henninger: Heilbronn, 1877.

Comment: By "power of stones", I mean the magical properties people think stone has in the Middle-Ages. Power like "Grant wealthyness", or "make you invincible".

Comment: I happened on a video from the British Museum recently which discussed some aspects of this in the [Curators Corner](https://youtu.be/uAJmvS_0RBY) series of videos.

Comment: @DorianTurba Thx for the updated direction. However, please add this info to the question as well. (In case you want this mostly "separated from the 'medical' aspects", please add that explicitly, or whether you want "going above and beyond mere medical healing, but into other spheres of 'power'"

Comment: Is my last edit ok for you on this point ?

Comment: @DorianTurba All posts can always be improved approximating more perfection. That said, if you are satisfied, then I am as well. If you want  more specifics for this question, keep editing, or criticising this A, as I would have to guess how to improve this A, (without merely expanding it according to how *I want to understand* the question…) ;)

Comment: For me, you provide everything I need : Where to look, and why.

Comment: "scientifically mostly discredited idea" -- _mostly_?

Comment: @WayneConrad Exactly. Pubmed lists a few, some small Gallic villagers still out there, [not](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10776231) all from TCM or ayurveda… Seriously: these *are* just minerals. To pulverise, dissolve, ingest, (Succinic acid, from Amber?), find a few have useful effects. Some can be used topically, mostly for bio-chemical effects, some for physical. Apart from placebo (which is useful as well) the swings and frequencies of course lack any evidence. I never saw a successful demonstration of invincibility. But then: most precious stones do increase your wealth… ;)